# flutter bloc cubit me genera un ProviderNotFoundException al guardar un formulario

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando guardar la información de un formulario para guardar una nueva "lista de la compra" y me genera el error ProviderNotFoundException al intentar guardar. He realizado la pagina principal con el listado de "listas de la compra" y flutter-bloc con cubit y al pulsar añadir, me navega a otra pantalla donde meter el nombre de la nueva lista para darla de alta. ¿Le tendría que pasar el contexto al navegar? ¿Porque no coge el contexto si "CreateShopListFormView" es un widget hijo de HomeView?

En ShopListsListView tengo un BlocBuilder sin BlocProvider que genera y muestra la lista correctamente.

El error que me genera es este:

> The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:
>
> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this CreateShopListFormView Widget

HomeView (Ventana principal)

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<ShopListCubit>(create: (_) => ShopListCubit()..init())
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Shop List'),
          ),
          body: const ShopListsListView(),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => CreateShopListFormView(),
              ));
            },
            tooltip: 'Crear Lista de la compra',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

ShopListCubit

```
class ShopListCubit extends Cubit<List<ShopList>> {
  ShopListCubit() : super([]);

  // final ShopListRepository _shopListRepository;

  void init() {
    //TODO: Call services

    final list = List.generate(
        10, (index) => ShopList(id: index, title: 'Shop list $index'));
    emit(list);
  }

  void createShopList(ShopList shopList) async {
    //TODO: call services
    final list = state;
    shopList.id = state.length + 1;
    list.add(shopList);
    emit(list);
  }
}
```

Clase ShopList

```
class ShopList extends Equatable {
  int id;
  final String title;

  ShopList({required this.id, required this.title});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error clásico no solo cuando usan `Provider/flutter_bloc`, sino también cuando tratan de usar cosas relacionadas con InheritedWidget.

Puedes revisar este video para entender como funcionan los `InheritedWidgets` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57CCj9UH_Gw

Este es el gráfico de tu árbol de widgets.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes observar que el Cubit solo cubre la rama del `HomeView`, debido a que lo creaste ahí.

Ese Provider/Bloc, no está disponible en el widget que abres usando el Navigator, ya que está en una rama del mismo nivel (diferente a como lo tienes en ShopListsListView, que pertenece al mismo árbol/rama).

Si deseas que el Cubit esté disponible, tendrías que declararlo arriba del `MaterialApp`, de ese modo, cualquier widget/página que abras, podrá acceder a él. De lo contrario tendrías que usar callbacks o retornar un valor de la página que abriste, para poder comunicarte con el widget anterior y acceder al Cubit.

Comment: He realizado lo de poner el Cubit en la primera clase "MyApp" donde se crea MaterialApp y ahora lo ejecuta bien. Lo único que no realiza es refrescar el listado en ShopListListView al volver a la pantalla home

Comment: intentaste con emit(List.from(list)); en lugar de emit(list);  en  void createShopList(ShopList shopList) async {   ?

Comment: Finalmente lo he conseguido copiando con final List<ShopList> list = List.from(state); y luego añadiendo el elemento y emitiendo list. Muchas gracias!